# How to Install Flashforge FlashPrint 3D app in Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, manpage

Sorry.. completely new to linux so go easy..  and none of the .man threads seem to make any sense to me.  I have downloaded the [flashprint 3d](https://www.flashforge.com/download-center) software from flashforge and within the zip file (extracted within the download folder) is a single .man file.  I have no idea how to run or install it, any help much appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think the software is for Ubuntu?

Comment: software is for Linux, i just have ubuntu version

Comment: It is unclear why you think it is for Ubuntu, there is no link to the download page. It's hard to help, given the limitations.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install the .man file by simply changing the name of it from `.man` to `.deb` (I am running PopOS, which is largely based on Ubuntu.), and my system immediately recognized it as a Debian binary.

The way I figured this out was simply using the `file` command to determine the filetype.

Answer (score 0):

There's a general guideline (or 'convention') in Linux that a .man file is a manual. The FlashPrint 3D folks have a different way, so it is not surprising you're asking for help.  Here's how:

Go to the FlashPrint 3D [Download Center](https://www.flashforge.com/download-center).

Choose **Software Download** from the left side tabs. [image]

There are multiple different packages to download. Select the app you want. There will be multiple versions. Look for the version which is described as "Support System: **Linux64**" if you have Ubuntu 64-bit or "Support System: **Linux 32** if you have a 32-bit version of Ubuntu. Click on its download button to the right.

[image]

A ZIP file will download. Extract the .tar file underneath the .man file in that ZIP file. There are two folders underneath  **.**  "a dot" which are **etc** and **usr** - each with subdirectories beneath them.

There's a PDF file with instructions under *usr\share\FlashPrint\doc* named *Flashprint-UserGuide-en_US.pdf* (plus versions for Taiwan and Mainland China, named appropriately). Follow those instructions, which vary according the the model of printer you have.

Comment: Hi K7AAY, thanks every so much for looking into this - i downloaded version 4.2 zip file but there is only a single .man file in it?  Im not sure what you mean by extract the .tar file as I dont see it?   I tried a lower version 4.1 linux64 and that had a .deb file.....  thanks for ongoing support and patience, be great if i could sort this

Comment: Extract the .tar file underneath the .man file in that ZIP file.  There are compressed files and directories inside that .man file you need to unzip.